# Filtering elements by taxonomy slug

Tags: taxonomy, slug

In my theme's article page (single.php) I have the following code filtering a div to be shown only on certain category:

```
<?php $categoria_post = the_category_id($categoria_post);
if ($categoria_post == 760) : ?>
<div>
...
</div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now I need to filter other div considering only the taxonomy slug (series_especiais), ignoring the id:

```
<?php $especiais = the_terms('slug','taxonomy-name');
if ($especiais == 'series_especiais') : ?>
```

But this code above doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

The way this taxonomy was created:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_tax' );

    function create_post_tax() {
        register_taxonomy(
            'series_especiais',
            'post',
            array(
                'label' => __( 'Séries Especiais' ),
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'series_especiais','with_front' => true ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for `the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/). It requires at least two parameters - the post ID, and the taxonomy name. You're not giving it either of these (I am of course assuming your taxonomy isn't called `taxonomy-name`).

However, you're also using the wrong function for the situation. **`the_terms()` is used to display (i.e. echo out) a list of terms**, not to compare them in an `if` statement. The function you're after is `get_the_terms()`. One thing to note is that a lot of WordPress functions follow a similar naming scheme: generally, a function starting with `get_` will return the value (great for comparisons, or for saving for later), whereas a function starting with `the_` will echo the value out.

So, let's look at `get_the_terms()`. Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), the required parameters are similar: the post ID (or post object), and the taxonomy name. So, we'd be looking at something like this:

```
$especiais = get_the_terms( $post, 'taxonomy-name' );
// replace taxonomy-name with the name of your taxonomy!
```

This will return an array of term objects, rather than a single term (you can verify this by running `print_r( $especiais );` - using print_r() is a great way to confirm what data you're getting back from a function, and is generally a good habit to get into when you're debugging code).

Then finally, we need to check through that array for the slug you're after. But not before we confirm that we actually *did* get an array back - you can never be too sure (especially if there were no terms assigned at all, or we made a mistake in the name of our taxonomy):

```
if( is_array( $especiais ) && count( $especiais ) ) { // is it an array, and with items?
  foreach( $especiais as $term ) { // loop through each term...
     if( $term->slug === 'series_especiais' ) { // ...till we find the one we want!
       ?>
       <div> put your div and other content here </div>
       <?php
       break; // avoid searching the rest of the terms; we've already found what we want
     }
  }
}
```

So the lesson to learn is: always look up the documentation for the functions you use. The [official Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) is an excellent place to start, otherwise often just Googling the function name will help too.

---

**EDIT:** After our discussion in the comments, it turns out there was a bit of confusion over terms and taxonomies. Given in your case the taxonomy name is 'series_especiais' and you want to just determine whether the post has *any* term in this taxonomy, you can skip the `foreach` loop entirely. Here's a rewrite:

```
$especiais = get_the_terms( $post, 'series_especiais' );

if( is_array( $especiais ) && count( $especiais ) ) { // is it an array, and with items?
  ?>
  <div> put your div and other content here </div>
  <?php
}
```

Much simpler :) I'll leave the rest of the above code here too because it might help someone else!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the id of the taxonomy I want. That's where I'm stucked.

Comment: @aarede Do you mean the name of the taxonomy? When you're viewing the terms in the admin, check the URL of the page - the name (or rather, slug) of the taxonomy should be in there.

Comment: this taxonomy was created (by a person who's not in the project anymore) to group 2 categories.
I searched some ID even in database, but there's no ID number related to this custom taxonomy (named 'series_especiais').
Now I need to add a filter that includes a div only on articles under this 'series_especiais' custom taxonomy.
The first code example in my question works fine filtering a div to be shown in certain category ID articles, but now I need to do the same on that pseudo-category apparently without ID.

Comment: @aarede It sounds like there might be some confusion between a term and a taxonomy. The code I gave you, building from what you had originally, assumes `series_especiais` is the slug of the term. Is it in fact the slug of the taxonomy? (Note that, for clarity's sake, `category` is the slug of the default category taxonomy, where, eg. `posts-about-me` might be the slug of a term under the category taxonomy).

Comment: Yep, 'series_especiais' is the slug of the taxonomy.

Comment: @aarede Ook got it. In that case the code you need is much simpler - you can skip the foreach loop entirely; all you need to do is ensure that you get terms back :) See the edit to my answer; trust this is what you're after?

Comment: it doesn't work.
Think the way this taxonomy was created (on edit above) can help.

Comment: @aarede Ok two things to try - try including [register_taxonomy_for_object_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) after your register_taxonomy() call; also, what is $categoria_post equal to? I was assuming it was set earlier on but perhaps I shouldn't have assumed that. You want the post ID or post object, so try $post instead.

Comment: Thank you very, very much!
Changing $categoria_post to $post makes it work.

Comment: @aarede Excellent! I'll edit my answer to clarify this. I did touch on it in the first part of my answer but not the second part :) If this solved your issue, you can use the check mark to the left of the answer to mark it as 'answered' - more details here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @aarede By the way, you can read more about how the `$post` variable works on the [Codex entry for The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: I'll do it for sure!